# Windows 8 KeyBinding

Tags: wpf, xaml

In Windows Desktop applications you can create a keyboard shortcut for the application (e.g. `Escape` to exit) using `RoutedCommands`, `CommandBindings`, and `KeyBindings`. But I cannot find any way to do this with Windows 8 and 8.1 metro apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AutomationProperties.AccessKey`  or `AutomationProperties.AcceleratorKey` (non-mnemonic shortcut keys) *to document* access keys, this information passed to users via *assistive technologies*.

What you really should do is to use `KeyDown` or `KeyUp` events, According to **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868161.aspx)**  :

> **Important**  Setting AutomationProperties.AcceleratorKey or
>   AutomationProperties.AccessKey doesn't enable keyboard functionality.
>   It only reports to the UI Automation framework what keys should be
>   used, so that such information can be passed on to users via assistive
>   technologies. The implementation for key handling still needs to be
>   done in code, not XAML. You will still need to attach handlers for
>   KeyDown or KeyUp events on the relevant control in order to actually
>   implement the keyboard shortcut behavior in your app.

Try this (e.g **Ctrl + Q** to **Close Application** ) :

XAML :

```
<Grid  KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown" KeyUp="Grid_KeyUp">
    <Button Content="Exit" AutomationProperties.AcceleratorKey="Control Q" />
</Grid>
```

Code :

```
public bool isCtrlKeyPressed { get; set; }

private void Grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Control) isCtrlKeyPressed = true;
    else if (isCtrlKeyPressed && e.Key == VirtualKey.Q)
    {
        Application.Current.Exit();
    }
}

private void Grid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Control) isCtrlKeyPressed = false;
}
```